# Samba share read only for guests, read write for authenticated users

Tags: permissions, samba, shared-folders

Is it possible to have a samba share read only for guests, and read write for authenticated users?

If I put guest ok on an share then I am not prompted for a password, and effectively logged as guest with read only rights. But I want to be authenticated so that I can also write.

Could anyone provide a sample smb share stanza to achieve this?

Answer (score 25):

Edit `/etc/samba/smb.conf`

```
# command line
sudo -e /etc/samba/smb.conf

# graphical
gksu gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf
```

Add in the `write list` paramter to your share definition, add in your list of users allowed write access.

```
write list = user1 user2 user3
```

You can use `read list` as well

```
read list = guest, nobody
```

So ...

```
[share]
comment = Ubuntu Share
path = /your/samba/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
write list = user1 user2 user3
create mask = 0755
```

If you need finer grain of control, you can use acl (access control lists) on the server.

Comment: That does not work: `lp_bool(guest nobody): value is not boolean!`

Comment: this answer is wrong. `read only` can be only  `yes` or `no`, can't have usernames or groups as its value.

Comment: I tried setting `read only` to `guest nobody` as suggested, but all it did was remove guest access to my share altogether, as if `guest ok` had been `no`. Using `write list` worked like a charm, just a shame I'll have to update it for every new user I add.

Answer (score 10):

Read only parameter is a Boolean value, so this should be more like one of the following:

```
[share]
comment = Ubuntu Share
path = /your/samba/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = no
read list = guest nobody
write list = user1 user2 user3
create mask = 0755

[share]
comment = Ubuntu Share
path = /your/samba/share
browsable = yes
guest ok = yes
read only = yes
write list = user1 user2 user3
create mask = 0755
```